# How to get current user ID in array meta_value?

Tags: users, query

Here is example:

```
$args=array(
   'meta_key'       => 'Something',
   'meta_value'      => '',//here goes current used ID by default.
   'meta_compare'   => '=', 

);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->user_login . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

This results all users user name, But I need to echo only those users name whose `meta_key=` something but `meta _value` is equal to current user ID.

How can I get the current user(log in user) ID in the `meta_value` by default?

Answer (score 1):

`WP_User_Query` is a user search. This sentence...

> But I need to echo only those users name whose meta_key= something but
>   meta _value is equal to current user ID.

... suggests that that is not really what you want. I think you can accomplish this with:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$meta = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'Something', true);
if (!empty($meta)) {
  // your current user has the "Something" meta key set
}
```

Since you are restricting the query to the current user ID I don't see why you'd need to query, unless this is some kind of cross linking system. If if is you can put the current user ID into the query just like about.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$args=array(
   'meta_key'       => 'Something',
   'meta_value'      => $current_user->ID,//here goes current used ID by default.
   'meta_compare'   => '=', 
);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Comment: Then mark that solution as "Accepted"

Comment: "Accepting" an answer means clicking the little check on the left under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in when the meta array is saved you can use the `$current_user` global variable.

```
$args=array(
   'meta_key'       => 'Something',
   'meta_value'      => $current_user->ID,
   'meta_compare'   => '=', 

);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But this is also echo same result, means all users list.

Comment: excellent. Please accept this answer as the correct answer if you find it was the most helpful (the little check mark next to the answer).

Comment: You have to click the check mark under the arrows next to my answer if you are "accepting" it.